# Removing spinner of ParseFacebookUtils on Login and Link

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform, facebook-android-sdk

I implemented logging in with facebook with `ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground`
and the linking with `ParseFacebookUtils.linkWithReadPermissionsInBackground`

The only problem I have is that it shows a spinner in the middle of my screen. After that it launches a webview of facebook.

[image]

Because of this the spinner sometimes overlap with my progress dialog. I bypassed this temporarily with:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
         progressDialog.show();
     }
}, 4000);
```

Although there are situations where the spinner slow because of the internet connection and I don't know how to solve this